# Add SVG Graphics in CHM (HTML Help Workshop)

Tags: svg, chm, html-help-workshop

I'm trying to use SVG-Graphics in a CHM-File. The CHM is created by HTML Help Workshop. Unfortunately the svg files don't show in my compiled chm. (Everything works fine in HTML)

I already added this `<meta>` to display my SVG Graphics

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

I need to copy my SVG-Graphics in my project (*.hhp file).

How I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG Graphics in CHM (Html Help Workshop)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026440/svg-graphics-in-chm-html-help-workshop)

Comment: I already saw this topics but for me, the problem is, to copy my sources files *.svg into my project *.hhp

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22697322/113116) helps.

Comment: Yes, I just solved my problem now with this solution. Thanks a lot dude :)